# CleanUp excel interop c#

Tags: c#, excel, com, interop

I'm saving links to excel file, but once i saved it the excel process is still runnning.
How i should relase this excel com object?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];

for (int i = 0; i < Links.Count; i++)
{
   sheet.Cells[i + 1, 1] = Links[i];
}

book.SaveAs("test.xlsx");

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
sheet = null;
book.Close(true, null, null);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);
book = null;
app.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
app = null;
```

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects

Comment: Look at my code, i'm releasing every object.

Comment: @KeithPayne is referring to the undeclared Workbooks and  Worksheets collections and the "two dots“ issue.

Comment: There's a Range interface reference being used in this code that you can never get to, it is entirely invisible.  Using ReleaseComObject() is just plain wrong.  Backgrounder [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130382/understanding-garbage-collection-in-net/17131389#17131389)

Comment: @Keith Payne - right sorry, stupid me. I didn't read a whole post. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "sheet.Cells" is a reference that you have to release:

```
var cells = sheet.Cells;

...

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cells);
```